# Changes to multiple entities within a single transaction

Tags: python

I am trying to make changes to multiple entities within a single transaction in app engine platform. As I understand in order to succeed doing so, App Engine needs to know in advance which entities will be updated together, so it knows to store them in a way that supports transactions. And therefore, user must declare that an entity belongs to the same entity group as another entity when you create the entity.

How do I declare that one entity belongs to another entity group in creation time?

Answer (score 2):

Using [parent](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model) argument to model constructor

Answer (score 0):

Just take obj of first class as a parent parameter in second class constructor...

like

```
class GroupA(db.Model):
    counterA = db.IntegerProperty()

class ExampleA(db.Model):
    exampleA = db.IntegerProperty()

def increment_counterA():

    obj = GroupA()
    obj.counterA = '89'
    obj.put()

    obj1 = ExampleA(parent = obj)
    obj1.exampleA = 90
    obj1.put()

class implementGroupA(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        db.run_in_transaction(increment_counterA)


def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', implementGroupA)],
                                         debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```